# Print first 50 number which are divisible by each number from 1 to 10

Tags: php, for-loop, nested-loops

To print first 50 number which are divisible by each number from 1 to 10 I've done this, now how can I Do the division test task in inner loop?

```
for ($i = 1, $j = 1; $j <= 50; $i++) {
    if ($i % 1 == 0 && $i % 2 == 0 && $i % 3 == 0 && $i % 4 == 0 && $i % 5 == 0 && $i % 6 == 0 && $i % 7 == 0 && $i % 8 == 0 && $i % 9 == 0 && $i % 10 == 0) {
        echo "$i\n";
        $j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the concrete problem? Also your solution should work, why do you want to change it? You should add the `homework`-tag, if this is a homework.

Comment: @JanDvorak He does, even if it's a slightly unorthodox way (the test-expression is based on `$j` and not the count-variable `$i`)

Comment: I think JanDvorak misunderstood.

Comment: @KingCrunch you're right; note that I only ever use `for` if I'm not changing the iteration variable inside the loop (and it's the iteration variable and only the iteration variable that I'm changing).

Comment: @KingCrunch: no he ***shouldn't*** add the 'homework' tag (regardless of whether it is, or not), [it's been deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) for some time, now.

Comment: it's still a rather "homework-y" question

Comment: And your point is..? The [tag:homework] tag is deprecated. Have a glance at [the discussion here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag) for why.

Comment: @DavidThomas Well, "some time" is relative ;) Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++)
{
        $j = $i * 2520;
        echo "$j\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I got a question how did u get 2520?

Comment: @EdnanHossain the least common multiple of 1..10

Comment: I didn't see your answer till after I posted mine - you beat me!

Answer (score 2):

Flip the question on it's head.  Rather than searching for divisions, just multiple them out:

```
$min = 5 * 7 * 8 * 9; // Min number is 5 * 7 * 8 * 9. (1,2,3,4,6,10 are implied)  Every number that meets the condition is a multiple of this.
for ($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++)
{
  echo $min * $i; 
  echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: ++ for your explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can *nest* loops and use the *modulus operator* (`%`).

```
for ($i = 1, $count = 0; $count < 50; $i++) {
    $good = true;
    for ($j = 2; $j <= 10; $j++) {
         if ($i % $j != 0) {
             $good = false;
             break;
         }
    }

    if ($good) {
        echo "$i\n";
        $count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Thanks** it works but it's printing first 51 number, I think we should set $count = 1;

Comment: @EdnanHossain Edited: changed from `$count <= 50` to `$count < 50`. My mistake.

Comment: thanks! can u please tell me which is the better option to use and why? please dont mind I'm just curious. $count = 1; or $count < 50;

Comment: @EdnanHossain Whether to start counting at zero or one is almost a religious subject amongst programmers. The start-at-zero method is probably more common, but both have their advantages.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to test if they are multiple of `9`, `8`, `7` and `5` and if so, increment the `j` counter. When `j` reachs `50`, the main loop is broken.

```
$div = array(9,8,7,5);
function isMultipleOf10($num){
    for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){
        if($num%$div[$i]!=0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
$i = 1;
$j = 0;
while($j<50){
    if(isMultipleOf10($i)){
        echo $i . "\n";
        $j++;
    }
    $i++;
}
```